# Using grouped and non-grouped column in the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with payment requests.

```
PaymentId (UNSIGNED INT AI)
ClientId (USINGNED INT)
Amount (FLOAT)
PayTo (DATE)
```

Because for PayTo there are usually not more than 2-3 distinct values (per client) I want to create the list - how much money should be paid up to this day. Do I was looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT PayTo, SUM(IF(PayTo <= PayTo, Amount, 0)) as AmountThisDate 
FROM Payments 
WHERE ClientId='%d' 
GROUP BY PayTo
ORDER BY PayTo DESC
```

But I'm 100% sure

```
PayTo <= PayTo
```

won't work.

What is the correct way to access GROUP BY Column and TABLE column at once if it is the same column?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: the field name is PayTo or PayDate?

Comment: `PayDate <= PayDate` is always EQUAL

Comment: my fault, PayTo is the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a cumulative sum.  Here is a method using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p1.PayDate,
       (select sum(p2.amount)
        from Payments p2
        where p2.ClientId = p.ClientId and
              p2.PayDate <= p.PayDate
       ) as AmountThisDate
FROM Payments p1
WHERE p1.ClientId='%d' 
GROUP BY p1.PayDate 
ORDER BY p1.PayDate DESC;
```

Performance will be improved by having an index on `payments(ClientId, PayDate, Amount)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PayDate, SUM(IF(PayDate <= current_date(), Amount, 0)) as AmountThisDate 
FROM Payments 
WHERE ClientId='%d' 
GROUP BY PayDate 
ORDER BY PayDate DESC
```

Is this what you were looking for?